# jQuery: why should I use traversal instead of pseudo selectors?

Tags: jquery, traversal, pseudo-element

Why is this:

```
$("div#fruit").children().children("#orange");
```

[^ Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1bvq4c28/3/)

---

..preferred over this?:

```
$("div#fruit ul#citrus li.orange");
```

[^ Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1bvq4c28/2/)

---

They both have the exact same functionality, however the first method traverses the DOM whereas the second method is using pseudo selectors.

I've heard that traversing the DOM, as opposed to using pseudo selectors, is the way to go. Why is that?

Comment: Firstly, chaining `children()` methods is bad practice - use `find()`. Secondly, it's all down to personal preference and the specific situation. There's no right or wrong.

Comment: Thirdly, those two code snippets don't have the exact same functionality.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216838/is-jquery-traversal-preferred-over-selectors

Comment: Use CSS selectors whenever it is possible.It's faster and less error prone. (Voting to close as "primarily opinion based".)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks, will note.

Comment: @Juhana Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @RinoRaj Thanks for the link!

Comment: Traversing the DOM is often preferred over pseudo-selectors because it offers better performance. However, what you have here are real selectors, not pseudo-selectors. For selectors that work natively with `document.querySelectorAll()` such as these ones, it's actually faster to use the selectors.

Comment: @LansanaCamara Well there's the obvious difference between `.orange` and `#orange` which I assume is just a typo; but even with that changed the second one is much more specific. http://jsfiddle.net/1bvq4c28/4/

Comment: @Juhana Hmm, I see now. So by targeting the exact path with the CSS selectors, I'm being much more precise, as opposed to traversing the DOM and kind of sitting at an element until it's told to travel to the next element? Am I getting that right?

Comment: Er, well, the first one is "find div with id 'fruit', find its children (*any* children because you haven't specified), find their children, choose the element with id 'orange' among them."  The second is "find div with id 'fruit', find an ul element with id 'citrus' that's a descendant of #fruit *at any level*, then find its descendant li element with class 'orange' *at any level*." So they're actually completely different. The first one doesn't even specify the `ul#fruit` and `li.orange` selectors so I don't see how they could even be seen as the same.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarifications!