# jquery append to table id not to table inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

Im trying to add a table row to a table with a certain ID, but when appending, it also appends to tables inside my table which have different ID. I´ve searched for an answer, but no luck. I dont know what im doing wrong here is a jfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/n7cyE/1445/

//table

```
<table id="tbl_1">
<thead>
  <td>column 1</td>
  <td>column 2</td>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <td>
    <table id="tbl_2">
      <thead>
        <td>inside column 1</td>
        <td>inside column 2</td>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td></td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

//jquery

```
var recent = "<tr><td>added column 1</td><td>added column 2</td></tr>";
$("#tbl_1 tbody").append(recent);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `#tbl_1 > tbody` selector instead of `#tbl_1 tbody` like following.

```
$("#tbl_1 > tbody").append(recent);
```

`#tbl_1 tbody` selects all `tbody` inside `#tbl_1` where `#tbl_1 > tbody` selects only the child `tbody` of `#tbl_1`.

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly!! I couldnt find a tutorial or info with this code.

Comment: Or you can use the traversing methods like `$('#tbl_1').children('tbody')`

Comment: thanks @Marco your answer also works!! now i have 2 options!

Comment: I don't think it'll count so much in your case, but if you have any doubts about why use traversal, there's this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216838/is-jquery-traversal-preferred-over-selectors